# Only start pipeline in Gitlab CI when git tag does not start with String "Release" or "Test"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to start a build job only if there is no git tag present or if the git tag is not "Release_..." or "Test_...". This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` for testing:

```
dev:
  rules: 
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG != /^Test_.*/ && $CI_COMMIT_TAG != /^Release_.*/' 
  script:
    - echo "dev"


test:
  rules: 
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^Test_.*/'
  script:
    - echo "test"


prod:
  rules: 
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^Release_.*/'
  script:
    - echo "prod"
```

If I add the git tag `Release_2021-3.0.0`, the `dev` and the `prod` build job are started. Only the `prod` build job should be started. What's the issue in the rule for the dev build job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether variable is not matching regex you should use `!~` ([GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#compare-a-variable-to-a-regex-pattern))

---

In your specific example you need to fix the `dev` stage:

```yaml
dev:
  rules: 
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG !~ /^Test_.*/ && $CI_COMMIT_TAG !~ /^Release_.*/' 
  script:
    - echo "dev"
```

And then only `prod` job will get initiated on `Release_2021-3.0.0` tag.
You can check out small project example [here](https://gitlab.com/aviadlevy/stackoverflow-70281913)

Comment: Thanks, I was only looking at the Gitlab CI Reference, and not in the general CI/CD documentation.